# The necessary and sufficient conditions for a complex function to have primitive function

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, line-integrals

In many textbooks on complex analysis, there is a theorem about when a complex function have a primitive function.

In fact, for a continuous function
$$f\colon D\to\mathbb C,\qquad D\subset\mathbb C\,\,\text{a domain},$$
the following three statements are equivalent:

(a) $f$ has a primitive.

(b) The integral of $f$ over **any closed curve** in $D$ vanishes.

(c) The integral of $f$ over any curve in $D$ depends only on the beginning
and end points of the curve.

Here the curves mean piecewise smooth curves or more generally, rectifiable curves.

**My question:** changing the condition **any closed curve** (in the second item) to **any simple closed curve**, whether the conclusion still holds?

Imitating the proof on the Freitag'book maybe we can prove that if the integral along any closed polygon curve $\gamma$ (not simple polygon curve, the edges can intersect) is zero:
$$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0,$$
then $f(z)$ has a primitive in $D$.

**Another question:** Is it true that a closed polygon curve(may not simple curve) divides plane into finite parts.

If we can prove that a closed polygon curve(may not simple curve) divides a plane into finite parts, then we can deduce that if the integral of $f$ over **any simple polygon curves** in $D$ vanishes, then $f$ has a primitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us begin with some preparations.

- An *abstract line segment in $D$* is any pair $[z,z']$ of distinct points $z,z' \in D$ such that the geometric line segment $L(z,z') = \{ z + t(z'-z) \mid t \in [0,1]\}$ is contained in $D$. For each $w \in L(z,z')$ there exists a unique $t(w) \in [0,1]$ such that $w = z + t(w)(z'-z)$. We write $w \le w'$ and $w < w'$ if $t(w) \le t(w')$ and $t(w) < t(w')$, respectively.
  Each linear parameterization $\delta$ of $[z,z']$ (i.e. each curve $\delta : [a,b] \to D$ given by $\delta(t) = z + \frac{t-a}{b-a} (z'-z)$) produces an integral $\int_\delta f(z)dz)$. Obviously we have $\int_\delta f(z)dz) = \int_{\bar \delta} f(z)dz)$ for any two such linear parameterizations $\delta, \bar \delta$. This common value will be denoted by $\int_{[z,z']} f(z)dz$.
- An *abstract polygon curve in $D$* is a tupel $\zeta = [z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ of points in $D$ such that all $[z_{i-1},z_i]$, $i=1,\ldots, n$, are abstract line segments in $D$. We write $l(\zeta) = n$ and define $L_i = L(z_{i-1},z_i)$, $i = 1,\ldots,n$. Moreover we define $\int_\zeta f(z)dz = \sum_{i=1}^n  \int_{[z_{i-1},z_i]} f(z)dz$.
  Next we define $\zeta = [z_0,\ldots,z_n] \triangleleft \eta = [w_0,\ldots,w_{n+1}]$ if $\eta$ is obtained from $\zeta$ by inserting after some position $i < n$ any point $z \in L_{i+1} \setminus \{z_i, z_{i+1}\}$. Thus $\eta = [z_0,\ldots,z_i,z,z_{i+1},\ldots, z_n]$. The relation $\triangleleft$ generates an equivalence relation $\equiv$ on the set of abstract polygon curves in $D$. Each equivalence class contains a representive $\zeta$ with minimal $l(\zeta)$. It is easy to see that this $\zeta$ is uniquely determined, but we shall not need this fact. Clearly, if $\zeta \equiv \zeta'$, then $\int_\zeta f(z)dz = \int_{\zeta'} f(z)dz$.
  $\zeta$ is called *closed* if $z_n = z_0$.  In this case let us consider the intersections $L_{(i,j)} = L_i \cap L_j$ with $1 \le i < j \le n$. A non-empty intersection is either a *small intersection*, which means that $L_{(i,j)}$ contains only one point, or a *big intersection*, which means that $L_{(i,j)}$ contains more than one point in which case $L_{(i,j)}$ is a geometric line segment. The intersections $\Lambda_i = L_{(i,i+1)}$ with $i = 1,\ldots,n-1$ and $\Lambda_n = L_{(1,n)}$ are non-empty since $z_i \in \Lambda_i$. As the *trivial intersections of $\zeta$* we denote the $\Lambda_i$ which are small intersections.
  A closed $\zeta$ is called *simple* if each non-empty intersection is a trivial intersection.
- A *polygon curve in $D$* is any curve $\gamma : [a, b] \to D$ for which there exists  partition $a = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = b$ such that $\gamma \mid_{[t_{i-1},t_i]}$ is a linear parameterization of $[z_{i-1},z_i]$, where $z_j = \gamma(t_j)$.  Clearly $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = \int_{[z_0,\ldots,z_n]} f(z)dz$. The tuple $[z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ is an abstract polygon curve in $D$; it is called a *polygonization of $\gamma$*. There are infinitely many such polygonizations, but any two polygonizations are equivalent in the above sense.

We know that if the integral of $f$ along any closed polygon curve $\gamma$ in $D$ is zero, then $f(z)$ has a primitive in $D$.

Now assume that we only know that the integral of $f$ along any *simple* closed polygon curve $\gamma$ in $D$ is zero. By the above considerations this is equivalent to $\int_{[z_0,\ldots,z_n]} f(z)dz = 0$ for each *simple* closed abstract polygon curve $[z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ in $D$.

We want to show that $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$ for each closed polygon curve $\gamma : [a, b] \to D$. This is equivalent to showing that $\int_{[z_0,\ldots,z_n]} f(z)dz = 0$ for each closed abstract polygon curve $[z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ in $D$.

It suffices to consider closed abstract polygon curves of the following special type:

1. If $L_{(i,j)}$ is a small intersection, then the unique intersection point $z \in L_{(i,j)}$ is one of the points $z_{i-1}, z_i$ and one of the points $z_{j-1}, z_j$.
2. If $L_{(i,j)}$ is a big intersection, then $L_{(i,j)} = L_i = L_j$.

In fact, each closed abstract polygon curve $\zeta$ is equivalent to such a special one which can be constructed as follows:

For each small intersection $L_{(i,j)}$ insert $z$ between $z_{i-1}$ and $z_i$ if $z \ne z_{i-1}, z_i$ and between $z_{j-1}$ and $z_j$ if $z \ne z_{j-1}, z_j$.

For each big intersection $L_{(i,j)}$ is a geometric line segment $L(z,z')$. Since $L_{(i,j)} \subset L_i$, we may assume w.lo.g. that $z_{i-1} \le z  < z' \le z_i$. If $z_{i-1} < z$, insert $z$ after $z_{i-1}$, and if $z' < z_i$, insert $z'$ before $z_{i}$. This leads to the insertion at most two points between $z_{i-1}$ and $z_i$. Similarly, using $L_{(i,j)} \subset L_j$, we insert at most two points between $z_{j-1}$ and $z_j$.

It remains to prove that $\int_\zeta f(z)dz = 0$ for each special closed abstract polygon curve $\zeta$ in $D$. This will be done by induction on $l(\zeta)$.

Note that $l(\zeta) = 1$ is impossible because a single line segment cannot give a closed curve.

Thus the base case is $n = 2$. Then $\int_{[z_1,z_2]} f(z)dz = \int_{[z_1,z_0]} f(z)dz = - \int_{[z_0,z_1]} f(z)dz$, thus $\int_{[z_0,z_1,z_2]} f(z)dz = 0$.

Assume that $\int_{[z_0,\ldots,z_m]} f(z)dz = 0$ for all special closed abstract polygon curves with $m < n$.

Consider a special closed abstract polygon curve $\zeta = [z_0,\ldots,z_n]$ in $D$.

If $\zeta$ is simple closed, we are done. So let us consider a special closed abstract polygon curve which is not simple. In that case there exists an index pair $(i,j)$ such that $2 \le j - i \le n-1$ and $z_i = z_j$. Let $\zeta'$ denote the special closed abstract polygonal curve obtained from $\zeta$ by removing the entries at positions $i +1,\ldots, j$ and $\zeta'' = [z_i,\ldots,z_j$ which is also a special closed abstract polygonal curve. Clearly  $\int_\zeta f(z)dz = \int_{\zeta'} f(z)dz + \int_{\zeta'} f(z)dz $. Both summmands are zero because  $l(\zeta'), l(\zeta'') < n$.